# HashMap types cannot find symbol

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a class with some HashMap types:

```
private class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    private HashMap<String, String> Attribs;
    private HashMap<String, List<Attribs> >FragmentNode;
    private HashMap<String, List<FragmentNode> > ActivityNode;
```

When compiling, I'm receiving this errors:

```
cannot find symbol FragmentNode and Attribs.
```

If I modify declarations inserting raw types i.e. changing `HashMap<String, List<Attribs>` to `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>` compiler stops to complain.

Do I need to do this? Java doesn't understand type declarations like these?

Comment: Did you import those classes?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem? And are you really naming variables the same exact name as some classes? Why?

Comment: you should use `camel case` for your variables

Comment: `Attribs` and `FragmentNode` are variables not classes

Comment: @locoyou Yes, but for me Java shoudn't complain.

Comment: yes locoyou is right, and following the naming conventions attribute variables starts with lower case, this way you would not confuse Classes and variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing types with attributes.

If you want a specific hierarchy like this, you should define new classes:

```
class Attribs extends HashMap<String, String> {}
class FragmentNode extends HashMap<String, List<Attribs>> {}
class ActivityNode extends HashMap<String, List<FragmentNode>> {}
```

Then you can create members like this:

```
private class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private Attribs attribs;
    private FragmentNode fragmentNode;
    private ActivityNode activityNode;
}
```

Comment: There is no other way, really. Ok, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentNode` and `Attribs` are not a types, its a variables, you can't specify variables as types to `HashMap`.

You could do this instead:

```
private HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> FragmentNode;
```

Or you could create a class that has Attribs HashMap just like:

```
public class Attribs {

    private HashMap<String, String> Attribs;

}
```

Then :

```
 private HashMap<String, List<Attribs>> FragmentNode;
```

Comment: The first solution is what I want to avoid. I've been thought in the second approach. But, what if I have a big system. Is this the approach to follow? Isn't there a better solution.